# How to use sass/scss with partials for css-files and remain folder structure?

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I got a wordpress theme with a style.css and a style-mobile.css in the main folder and some partials in a subfolder css/globals (for style.css) and css/mobile (for style-mobile.css). I created scss-Files of the two css files in the main folder that import the partials in the subfolders.

With this line of code `sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compressed` executed in the main folder a style.css will automatically be created everytime when style.scss gets edited. The problem is that style.scss just imports the partials. When a partial gets edited nothing happens.

I tried `sass --watch css/globals:css/globals` and also `sass --watch _one_of_my_partials.scss:_one_of_my_partials.css --style compressed` in my subfolder but that didn't change anything.

So is there a way to make that work but remain folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just run this command to watch any file?

```
sass --watch sass:css
```

**EDIT:** OK, so it looks like your setup should be something like this:

```
- theme_folder/
  - sass/
    - style.scss
    - css/          
      - globals
        - some_partial.scss
        - _some_partial_without_compiled_file.scss
```

With this setup, you than run the following command:

```
sass --watch sass:.
```

This will result in all files compiled at root level. After first compilation, the file structure will look like this:

```
- theme_folder/
  -style.css
  - css/
    - globals/
      - some_partial.css
  - sass/
    - style.scss
    - css/          
      - globals
        - some_partial.scss
        - _some_partial_without_compiled_file.scss
```

I hope this is what you want to have.

Comment: That wouldn't work because of the folder structure. As I said the files are in different directories and I wanna keep that folder structure. But still thx! :)

Comment: Check out my edit. I think that's what you wanted to have.